# valueHasMutated with deferred updates does not work as expected

Tags: knockout.js

Suppose I have one observable and one subscription for that observable (call it reaction function). I want to trigger subscription using valueHasMutated when in fact no change was made to observable. This is because I want to run that reaction function from blur event, even if no change was made. In other 
instances I want reaction to run only on value change.

This works very well, focusing and clicking button generates pairs of console messages, as expected.

Until I use `deferUpdates`. When I uncomment `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;` on the first line, it shows only one "subscribe" and than series of "blur" without any "subscribe".

```js
// ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
var x = ko.observable(null);
x.subscribe(() => console.log("subscribe"));

var vm = {
  guiBlur: function() {
   console.log("blur");
    x.valueHasMutated();
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="event: {blur: guiBlur}">
<button>Focus input and then click me, do it repeatedly and watch console</button>
```

I tried `ko.tasks.runEarly()`, but no help.

Can anybody help, please?

Edit based on comments - I do not want to use notify always, because I want to manipulate observable from several places and react only on real value change. The only place I want reaction to run always is from blur event.

Comment: Have you see the mbest's answers at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/610 and https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1019 ?

Comment: same @Bludev notice, please read here github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2009 , mbest quote that 
`All change notifications are delayed, including when calling valueHasMutated manually. This means you can’t use valueHasMutated to force a rate-limited observable to notify an un-changed value` but 
`using notify: 'always' will allow you to use valueHasMutated` 
and change code like that:
`var x = ko.observable(null).extend({notify: 'always'});`. it worked !

Comment: I already tried `.extend({notify: 'always'})` but the problem is (as written in the question) I don't want to notify always, only force notify on blur. Value is also modified on other places, where I want "normal" behavior (not always). So it seem I need two observables, one "always" and one "normal" based on "always" somehow... Or can I disable deferring for specific observable?

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that You missed the parameter inside the subscription function...  You can check for yourself for a true `value` change, and skip the reaction when the `value` has not really changed, maybe this helps:

```js
ko.options.deferUpdates = true;

function VM () {
  var self = this;
  this.x = ko.observable(null);
  this.x.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    var oldValue = self.x.peek();
    console.log("Reaction triggered");
    if(oldValue === newValue) return;
    console.log("Value has changed");
  });
  this.guiBlur = function () {
    console.log("blur");
    self.x.valueHasMutated();
  };
}

var vm = new VM;

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="event: {blur: guiBlur}">
<button>Focus input and then click me, do it repeatedly and watch console</button>
<button onclick="vm.x.notifySubscribers('X');">Set x</button>
```

Comment: OK, I had some trouble understanding the example, because that `peek` did not work for me, but I think I got the idea - notify always and remember the old value. Yes, it does the trick, somewhat crude to implement it every time, but maybe it could be reworked to extender. IMHO it still will be useful to be able to disable deferring for the single observable.